# Custom route doesn't work with default mvc route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm following the [Microsoft Contoso University Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to learn MVC.

So far I've created 3 Models

1. Course
2. Enrollment
3. Student

And I have 2 Controllers

1. HomeController
2. StudentController

I can view a list of students, details about the students including what courses and what grades they have in the courses, edit student details, and add new students.

At this point, I wanted to learn more about routing since I had been using the default Map Route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I have a database of students that all have unique last names. I'm aware that doing this is not normally recommended since last names are not unique, but it works for this small learning project. So what I wanted to achieve was to be able to type in `/students/{action}/{lastname}` and view details about the student. so I created a new action method in my student controller.

```
public ActionResult Grab(string studentName)
{
    if (studentName == null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    var student = db.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LastName.ToLower() == studentName.ToLower());
    if (student == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    return View(student);
}
```

And I added a new route in my RouteConfig.cs file

```
//Custom route
routes.MapRoute(
    name: null,
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{studentName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "Grab", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And finally I created a new view called Grab that shows details about the student.

Now when I type in `/student/grab/Norman` it gives me the details of the student with the last name Norman

[image: Laura Norman]

This is great. But now I have a problem. When I try to use some of my original URLs like `/Student/Details/1`
they no longer work. I get a 400 error.

The first thing I did was move my default route above the custom route I made

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
//Custom route
routes.MapRoute(
    name: null,
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{studentName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "Grab", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And this fixes that problem but causes a 400 error on my previously working grab route. How can I use both of these at the same time without getting a 400 error?

Here is my full RouteConfig.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace ContosoUniversity
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            //Custom route
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: null,
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{studentName}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "Grab", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


        }
    }
}
```

Here is my entire StudentController.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ContosoUniversity.DAL;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        private SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext();

        // GET: Student
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Students.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Student/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(student);
        }

        public ActionResult Grab(string studentName)
        {
            if (studentName == null)
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

            var student = db.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LastName.ToLower() == studentName.ToLower());
            if (student == null)
                return HttpNotFound();

            return View(student);
        }

        // GET: Student/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Student/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "LastName, FirstMidName, EnrollmentDate")]Student student)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Students.Add(student);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (DataException /* dex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            }
            return View(student);
        }

        // GET: Student/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(student);
        }

        // POST: Student/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EditPost(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var studentToUpdate = db.Students.Find(id);
            if (TryUpdateModel(studentToUpdate, "",
               new string[] { "LastName", "FirstMidName", "EnrollmentDate" }))
            {
                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (DataException /* dex */)
                {
                    //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
                }
            }
            return View(studentToUpdate);
        }

        // GET: Student/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(student);
        }

        // POST: Student/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
            db.Students.Remove(student);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

I'll provide any other details needed. Again I want to be able to type in `http://localhost:49706/Student/Details/1` or `http://localhost:49706/Student/Grab/Alexander` and get the same exact details since Alexander is has the studentID of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to differentiate  your custom route from the default route url

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //Custom route
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Students",
        url: "Student/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "Grab", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    //General default route
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Action parameters should also match the route template parameters

```
// GET: Student/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(int? id) {
    if (id == null) {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var student = db.Students.Find(id);
    if (student == null) {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(student);
}

public ActionResult Grab(string id) {
    if (id == null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    var student = db.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LastName.ToLower() == id.ToLower());
    if (student == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    return View(student);
}
```

This would now allow the following to be match correctly

```
Student/Details/1 
Student/Grab/Alexander
```

provided student with last name Alexander has the studentId of 1

Comment: Quick question. My url structure now needs to be /Student/Details?id=1 rather than Student/Details/1  which gives me a 400 error. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @onTheInternet, That should not be. update actions to use the same name as in the template `studentId` or what ever you decide to use once they are the same. Note how the name was changed from `id` to `studentId` in the answer to match the route template. All the actions that require the id should be changed to match. Or you could revert to making all of them `id` again, once the template is updated as well

Comment: I copied your code exactly and that fixed my issue. I dont know what I had wrong.  One final question. my index view for my student controller is is displaying an incorrect link for details. So rather then the link going to /student/Details/1 it shows /Student/Details?id=1 which gives me a 400 when I go to it.  I'm not sure how to fix this because my action link just looks like this @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID })

Comment: @onTheInternet, That needs to be updated to match place holder as well `@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { studentId=item.ID })`. Hear what. If all of your current code uses `id` I would suggest making all your parameter id instead of having to update all your code. just update the actions and routes. I'll update the answer to match

Comment: You have been immensely helpful. Thank you for your very clear instructions. You have given me great insight.

Answer (score 1):

Both routes are the same (from a pattern matching standpoint):

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}

{controller}/{action}/{studentName}
```

`id` and `studentName` are just placeholders. They hold no meaning other than that, so you essentially have a single route defined twice:

```
{controller}/{action}/{someindicator}
```

What ends up happening is that whatever route is hit first will serve the request.

Because of this, if you want to use the same "pattern", you need to differentiate the routes somehow. I would suggest indicating the action directly in the route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "StudentDetails",
                url: "{controller}/Details/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            //Custom route
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "GrabStudent",
                url: "{controller}/Grab/{studentName}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "Grab", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: Your answer was correct but I read the other one first. I upvoted you for having good content. Thank you for your time.